# Allow non-members of an OG to post group content

Tags: organic-groups, users

I'm building a website with the use of [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module. I need to allow all registered users (not only group members) to have permission to post nodes of a certain content type to any group. However I failed to achieve this behaviour as well as finding helpful info online. Can anyone please advise me on how to make this? Are any additional modules needed?

Answer (score 0):

You need the OG permissions overview menu (`admin/config/group/permissions`). You can find there permissions to let non-members post content.
[image]